Can a US-based contractor work for a French company?
I am a French citizen located in the US, working as an independent contractor within the US (I have a visa and work authorization).
A French company wants to hire my services.
What do I need to make sure I can work for them and receive pay?

Assuming you don't have any other business or properties in France, I don't think the fact you're a French citizen changes much, ultimately it's a business-to-business transaction and the rules would be the same if you were a US citizen so I am not sure it's within the scope of this site. I am not sure whether there is another site where it would fit better.

Just to be sure: We are talking about work you can do remotely, you are not planning to travel to France to do it, correct?

What kind of work authorization do you have?

@Relaxed the fact of being a French citizen could be very significant on the US side, as implied by user102008's question: many forms of work authorization in the US are limited to a particular employer.  I suppose that the fact that Julie is already working as an independent contractor suggests that she's probably okay, but I am by no means confident of that.

@phoog Yeah, I assumed the question was solely about the French side of things as Julie seemed to think she had all she needed on the US side but I forgot to ask if my understanding was correct.
